# IF condition in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query:

```
select
p.id AS id,
p.text AS text,
p.date AS date,
k.color AS color,
...

FROM

cform_mba_contacts p,
cform_mba_contacts_category_links o,
cform_mba_contacts_status k,
...

where

p.id_peoples = ".$this->id." AND
o.id_contacts = p.id AND
o.id_status = k.id AND
...

order by p.date
```

This query worked perfectly before the introduction of a new condition. I need to select that data with that conditions **and** only with `p.id_peoples = ".$this->id."`. I tried to use `UNION` but that didn't work. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

i resolve my problem by reading additional documentation on UNION operator
in order clause need to use not p.date but only date, and in second statement need to select  that count of columns, that selects in first statement

Comment: What exactly is your question or requirement of query??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is **UNION ALL**.

Comment: smthing like that ) but used UNION. i resolve my problem by reading additional documentation on UNION operator, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (@id IS NULL 
     OR 
     ( p.id_peoples = @id  
       AND o.id_contacts = p.id 
       AND o.id_status = k.id
     ))

ORDER BY p.date
```

Where `@id` is the parameter passed by `.$this->id.`.

The conditions `o.id_contacts = p.id AND o.id_status = k.id` will be applied only if the parameter passed by `.$this->id.` is not null.

Comment: you wrote @id IS NULL but then .$this->id. is not null
how is that possible? ) in different conditions that give me an error

Comment: @user1506183 The `AND` block in the `WHERE` clause can be dissected into two parts, the first one is `@id IS NULL` if it is false then the whole `AND` condition won't be executed there fore the `WHERE ` clause would be `WHERE 1 = 1` i.e, no where clause. If it is true then the `OR` block would be executed. This what I understand from your question. Isn't that behaviour what you asked for? and what error did you got?

Comment: i resolve my problem by reading additional documentation on UNION operator, thanks man

Comment: @user1506183 You're welcome. I just tried to help, glad to hear that your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE  p.id_peoples <> ".$this->id." 
       OR ( o.id_contacts = p.id AND
            o.id_status = k.id AND
            ...
          )
```

Comment: i resolve my problem by reading additional documentation on UNION operator, thanks

Comment: @user1506183 Nice. You should post your answer. So other people can also get help from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
create a string and execute the string at the last.

decalre @thequery varchar(max);
 set @thequery ='select * from emp'
if (1=1)
begin
set @thequery = @thequery + ' where emp_id =1'
end
else
begin
set @thequery = @thequery + ' where emp_id=0'
 end exec("@thequery ");
```